# How to create Crystal language Hash where values can be any type?

Tags: openapi, crystal-lang

I'm working on representing an API where a response contains a hash where the keys are of type `String` and the values can be of any type. Is there a way to represent this in Crystal?

I did not see a way to represent this looking through Crystal docs on types:

- https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.6/syntax_and_semantics/literals/index.html
- https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.6/syntax_and_semantics/literals/hash.html

In OpenAPI Spec, this is described as a free-form object:

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/#free-form

> Free-Form Objects
>
> If the dictionary values can be of any type (aka free-form object), use additionalProperties: true:
>
> `type: object`
> `additionalProperties: true`
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> `type: object`
> `additionalProperties: {}`

In Go, this would be represented as `map[string]any` or `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: Either initialize a literal with inferable values, or manually define a union type with all the possible types you're prepared to handle. Crystal can't infer a type you don't use, and generic type arguments aren't as generic as you'd expect. Since you still need to write code that knows how to process a value of a given type, you have a finite list of types anyway. Otherwise, just leave the type blank and let the compiler infer the possible types from caller arguments.

Comment: It's fairly easy to just create a massive list of the types you want like `String|Integer|UInt64` FWIW :)

Answer (score 3):

Given that everything is an object in Crystal, the following compiles for me:

`Hash(String, Object)`

> Everything is an object
>
> In Crystal everything is an object. The definition of an object boils down to these points:
>
> - It has a type
> - It can respond to some methods
>
> This is everything you can know about an object: its type and whether it responds to some method.
>
> An object's internal state, if any, can only be queried by invoking methods.

Ref: https://crystal-lang.org/reference/1.6/syntax_and_semantics/everything_is_an_object.html

Ref: https://crystal-lang.org/api/1.8.2/Object.html

Comment: `48 | when Hash(Symbol, Object)`
`                        ^-----`
`Error: can't use Object as generic type argument yet, use a more specific type`